# Get the count of most occurring element in a list at every iteration

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration, max

I need to fetch the most occurring ID in a list at every iteration I process the list. Its a huge list that contains positive/negative IDs. If ID is positive, increase the count for that ID; if negative, reduce the count for that ID.
Consider input list as below:

```
input_list = [6,6,6,2,2,-6,-6,-6,-2,-2]

input_list[0] = 6 -> Count of ID 6:1 ->max count at this iteration is 1
input_list[1] = 6 -> Count of ID 6:2 ->max count at this iteration is 2
input_list[2] = 6 -> Count of ID 6:3 ->max count at this iteration is 3
input_list[3] = 2 -> Count of ID 6:3, Count of ID 2:1 ->max count at this iteration is 3
input_list[4] = 2 -> Count of ID 6:3, Count of ID 2:2 ->max count at this iteration is 3
input_list[5] = -6 -> Count of ID 6:2, Count of ID 2:2 ->max count at this iteration is 2
input_list[6] = -6 -> Count of ID 6:1, Count of ID 2:2 ->max count at this iteration is 1
and so on..
```

Expected output:

```
[1,2,3,3,3,2,2,2,1,0]
```

Note: -6 means the count of ID 6 getting reduced by 1.

```
def getMAxIDAfterEachUpdate(input_list):
    res = []
    dic = {}
    for i in range(len(input_list)):
        tmp = abs(input_list[i])
        if tmp not in dic:
            tmp = 1
        else:
            # ID is negative, we decrement its count
            if input_list[i] < 0:
                dic[tmp] -= 1
            else: #its positive, increment its count
                dic[tmp] += 1
        res.append(max(dic.values())
    return res
```

Finding max value in dictionary at every iteration is expensive. Is there a better way to find the result?

Comment: Please further elaborate your question with examples or sample code and what error you are facing.

Comment: Why you think the current approach is time expensive ? You are only using single loop, so the complexity is O(n), which is good. Since need max count per iteration and  you are handling negative values also as deletion, I don't think you can reduce the complexity to O(logn) or O(1). The code you pasted look good for this problem.

Comment: @krishna The OP's current approach is *O(n x m)* where *n* is the size of the input and *m* is the number of unique IDs. Note the use of the `max` function inside a loop. With a better algorithm it is possible to improve the time complexity to *O(n)* where the number of unique IDs no longer matters.

Comment: @blhsing is there a better approach?

Comment: Yes, there is. It seems that this question has not been able to garner enough reopen votes even though I believev it is now clarified enough after the edits. Try reposting this as a new question so I can answer you there.

Comment: @blhsing The question is now open again.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with your approach using a simple dict to store counts of IDs is that dict values are unordered, so in each iteration a full scan of dict values must be performed in order to obtain the maximum value/ID count, resulting in a time complexity of *O(n x m)*, where *n* is the size of the input list and *m* is the number of unique IDs.

Since we know that the count of a given ID can only incremenet or decrement by 1 in each iteration, one way to optimize the algorithm is to store the ID count, along with the number of IDs sharing that count, in a node of a [doubly linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list) instead, and keep the counts stored in the nodes in ascending order in each iteration by either creating a new node with the new count or merging with the next/previous node if it shares the new count, while updating the node with the new number of IDs sharing the count, both operations of which takes *O(1)* time complextiy. Since the nodes are kept in ascending order of the counts, obtaining the maximum count is simply a matter of getting the count in the last node in *O(1)* time complexity, resulting in an improved overall time complexity of *O(n)*.

With `nodes` being the dict that maps ID to node, and `counts` being the doubly linked list where each node stores a pair of `count` and `number` of IDs sharing the count, using your sample input list of `[6, 6, 6, 2, 2, -6, -6, -6, -2, -2]` to illustrate the result at the end of each iteration:

```
Iteration 1, ID = 6:
    nodes = {6: node1}
    counts = [node1(count=1, number=1)] => max count = 1
Iteration 2, ID = 6:
    nodes = {6: node1}
    counts = [node1(count=2, number=1)] => max count = 2
Iteration 3, ID = 6:
    nodes = {6: node1}
    counts = [node1(count=3, number=1)] => max count = 3
Iteration 4, ID = 2:
    nodes = {6: node1, 2: node2}
    counts = [node2(count=1, number=1), node1(count=3, number=1)] => max count = 3
Iteration 5, ID = 2:
    nodes = {6: node1, 2: node2}
    counts = [node2(count=2, number=1), node1(count=3, number=1)] => max count = 3
Iteration 6, ID = -6:
    nodes = {6: node2, 2: node2}
    counts = [node2(count=2, number=2)] => max count = 2
Iteration 7, ID = -6:
    nodes = {6: node1, 2: node2}
    counts = [node1(count=1, number=1), node2(count=2, number=1)] => max count = 2
Iteration 8, ID = -6:
    nodes = {6: node1, 2: node2}
    counts = [node1(count=0, number=1), node2(count=2, number=1)] => max count = 1
Iteration 9, ID = -2:
    nodes = {6: node1, 2: node2}
    counts = [node1(count=0, number=1), node2(count=1, number=1)] => max count = 1
Iteration 10, ID = -2:
    nodes = {6: node1, 2: node1}
    counts = [node1(count=0, number=2)] => max count = 0
```

Here's an implementation of the algorithm using the `dllist` class in the [`llist`](https://ajakubek.github.io/python-llist/index.html) module for an efficient implementation of a doubly linked list:

```
from llist import dllist
from collections import namedtuple

count_number = namedtuple('count_number', ('count', 'number'))

def max_count_per_update(ids):
    nodes = {}
    counts = dllist()
    for id in ids:
        if not (node := nodes.get(key := abs(id))):
            if counts and (first := counts.first).value.count == 0:
                node = first
            else:
                node = counts.appendleft(count_number(0, 1))
        new_count = (current_node := node).value.count + (-1 if id < 0 else 1)
        next_node = node.prev if id < 0 else node.next
        if next_node and (next_value := next_node.value).count == new_count:
            (node := next_node).value = count_number(new_count, next_value.number + 1)
        else:
            insert = counts.insertbefore if id < 0 else counts.insertafter
            node = insert(count_number(new_count, 1), node)
        if new_number := (current_value := current_node.value).number - 1:
            current_node.value = count_number(current_value.count, new_number)
        else:
            counts.remove(current_node)
        nodes[key] = node
        yield counts.last.value.count
```

so that:

```
input_list = [6, 6, 6, 2, 2, -6, -6, -6, -2, -2]
print(list(max_count_per_update(input_list)))
```

outputs:

```
[1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0]
```

Demo on replit: https://replit.com/@blhsing1/InfantileSandybrownNanotechnology#main.py

Note that `llist` requires a C compiler, which isn't available in replit's Python environment so I have to use the bash envrionment instead and write a shell script to install `pip` and `llist` on the fly, which sometimes requires a rerun after installation to work for some reason.

Comment: If understand correctly "counts" is sorted dllist by current count. How this works if there are multiple nodes (id-s) having same count? That is, how is list updated when one of such nodes is to be updated, and need to skip by multiple nodes on left/right ?

Comment: You get the "sorted dllist by current count" part right, but you're missing the part where I store the count together with the number of IDs sharing the count, so any increment or decrement to an ID count always needs just one move to the right or left, either by merging with an existing node (if it shares the same count) or by creating a new node (if an existing node with the new count doesn't exist). Please see how iteration 5 evolves to iteration 6 and then to iteration 7 in my illustration above.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you need is bidirectional mapping of dict(key, counter) <-> ordered_dict(counter,set(key)).

You can implement this ony your own, or you can use exiting library.

https://grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sorteddict.html

Where main gist is using : https://grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sorteddict.html#sorteditemsview

```
sd = SortedDict()
siv = sd.items()
for i in input_list:
   k = abs(i)
   diff = 1 if i > 0 else -1
   if i in sd:
     sd[i] += diff
   else:
     sd[i] = diff
   k,c = siv[-1]
   print(k,c) # largest item and count
```

Comment: Note that an assignment to a key in a `SortedDict` requires a time complexity of [*O(log n)*](https://grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sorteddict.html#sortedcontainers.SortedDict.__setitem__), so doing it in a loop as your code is would result in a time complexity of *O(n log m)*.